# make array.map return specific type signature

Tags: typescript

Consider those two simple functions in **typescript**:

```
function produce(): Array<[number, number]> {
  return [[0, 1], [2, 3]];
}

function transform(input: Array<[number, number]>): Array<[number, number]> {
  return input.map(xy => [xy[0] + 1, xy[1] + 1]);
}

console.log(transform(produce()));
```

`transform` maps one the very same array of two-dimensional-integer-arrays to another. TypeScript compiler says:

```
Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number]'.
    Property '0' is missing in type 'number[]'.
```

Do I have to change the function's signature to `number[][]` (and therefore open the door for accidentally one ore poly dimensional arrays) or use an interface, or can I somehow define the return type of the mapping function to be exactly `Array<[number, number]>`?

Edit1:
Thanks to @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir I found out, that current Typescript actually don't show that error - but 3.1.1. does.

Comment: The code as posted does not error in the latest version https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE5wCYggUwBQCUAXIgIKqoCGAngDwDaYIAtgEY6oA0iTbHAugD5EAbwBQiRKhxQQqJPXoAGbgEZ+3egCZuAZn78A3GIC+YsaEiwEiKFTABnYHFTM8MMMhBQS5KnUYWdi4eIIFBYjIKGgZeYO448NEJKRk5JA8vKAA6ZkpkPAAPakQAXmF6YuV+RABqRFVuKvU6hv4CYzMxCAQHOAAbHGz+uABzPDtKR2dXPDRMbHwCZcMgA

Comment: Interesting! I use 3.1.1

Comment: I think I saw an improvement related to this in a version after 3.1

Comment: You can use an explcit annotation `return input.map((xy): [number, number] => [xy[0] + 1, xy[1] + 1]);`

Comment: Yeah, switching the playground to version `3.1.6` does reproduce this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inference in this scenario seems to have improved since 3.1. The simplest solution is to be explicit about the return type:

```
function produce(): Array<[number, number]> {
  return [[0, 1], [2, 3]];
}

function transform(input: Array<[number, number]>): Array<[number, number]> {
  return input.map((xy): [number, number] => [xy[0] + 1, xy[1] + 1]);
}

console.log(transform(produce()));
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.1.6#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE5wCYggUwBQCUAXIgIKqoCGAngDwDaYIAtgEY6oA0iTbHAugD5EAbwBQiRKhxQQqJPXoAGbgEZ+3egCZuAZn78A3GIC+YsaEiwEiKFTABnYHFTM8MMMhBQS5KnUYWdi4eIIFBYjIKGgZeYO448NEJKRk5JA8vKAA6ZkpkPDwAD2pIwL4QxNR+RABeYXoS5RqAakRVbib1RDb1AmMzMQgEBzgAGxxssbgAczw7SkdnVzw0TGx8Ai3DIA)